# How come the Windows OS hasn't been decompiled?

Tags: windows

As far as I'm aware, Windows hasn't been decompiled by anyone yet. Obviously it's complicated, but surely it should've been done by now to some degree?

My thinking behind this is that if the end-user has access to the software, and the computer is able to run it, then even an obfuscated version of it must be obtainable?

I'm obviously missing something, I'm just not sure what.

Comment: Why would you do that? What's the benefit? I'll let the fact that this is illegal slide, but what's the point?

Comment: 50 million lines, complied into optimized machine code. You can easily disassembly it, but [getting back](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/4202) from optimized assembly to 50 million of source code lines should take you hardly less [amount of labour](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=305678) than it went into writing it in the first place.

Comment: Apart from what @Luaan correctly pointed out above: you cannot get back to the source code from some compiled, binary blob you have. There simply is information missing you cannot somehow reconstruct.

Comment: @Luaan I'm simply curious, it was a hypothetical question.

Comment: @GSerg So it solely relies on the shear size of it, but would still be possible to decompile into an obfuscated state?

Comment: Hypothetical questions still need to have a point, otherwise they're just idle questions. Those usually aren't on-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @arkascha But like I said earlier, if a machine can read and run code at runtime, so it must be possible to decompile into an obfuscated state?

Comment: @Luaan I'm obviously on the wrong site then, I just wanted to get a better understanding of how it worked.

Comment: @user7126040 Please see http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ then.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here by "obfuscated". As already pointed out by @GSerg you could convert it to assembler code, that is about how far you can get. And then? What have you gained with that?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, I didn't realise that existed!

Comment: @arkascha Yeah, that's about as far as I expected anyone to get realistically. As far as I'm aware there's deobfuscating tools available - couldn't that same logic be applied to the assembler/obfuscated code?

Comment: No. As said there is information missing in the compiled code that you cannot reconstruct. I would advise to stop using the term "obfuscated" in this. There is no step where any obfuscation has taken place when you have `c++` code and compile and link that into binary blobs. And, on top, the main question asked at the beginning of this discussion remains unanswered: what have you gained? MS could certainly open their source code and release it, that would not change much and certainly would not really help people using that system. The only reason speaking against that is the code quality ;-)

Comment: @arkascha Well, I've seen Windows source codes in the past (working on an embedded project, so mainly Windows CE). They looked rather competent to me :) I'm not sure if Microsoft still offers source code licenses for Windows today - it was rare enough in the days before Windows Update and when a system that hasn't been updated in a month wasn't an instant target. Having a custom build of Windows today would be a bit hazardous, to say the least.

Comment: Short from the drastic impracticality and the low gains of the task, Microsoft will *always* outpace anybody's effort.  Updates and new versions come too quick to keep up.  Substantial parts of the actual source code of Windows 2000 was leaked, an oops committed by Mainsoft.  Nobody cared :)

Comment: well.. react OS Dev's claim that they reverse engineering windows part by part and write their own code by taking "inspiration" from decompilation.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing preventing Windows from being decompiled (apart from EULA and similar legal bindings, of course). As you noted, the code must run on the CPU at some time, and the CPU must read the code from memory, and you can read from memory too. Some parts of the system can be a bit trickier, since to run the OS you need to give the OS some exclusive priviledges (that's how most modern protected OSes work), but it's nothing that can't be worked around. In any case, there's not a lot of effort to prevent Windows decompilation - that would have barely any benefit, while making debugging, error reporting and similar harder. Microsoft even goes so far to provide a special debug version of Windows that's even more tailored for software development.

The main point is that there's little reason to decompile Windows. What practical use would such a massive effort have? And if you're a corporation that needs access to Windows source codes (for example, when developing embedded solutions), you can get them. Just because Windows isn't open source doesn't mean the sources aren't available.

If you're not someone who needs their own version of Windows (common in the times of  Windows CE), there's even less of a reason to decompile Windows. You need to stick to the defined public APIs anyway - that's a good practice regardless of whether the software is open source or not. APIs are contracts - implementation details you'd get through decompiling aren't. They might very well change with the next security hotfix or such. This is especially important given how serious Windows is about compatibility - it's quite rare for an update (or even a new major release) to break compatibility with old software.

So, if you want to decompile Windows, there's nothing technical that's really preventing you from doing so. But you're looking at tens of millions of lines of source code that was compiled by very smart compilers, with bits of handwritten optimised assembly thrown around, tons of compatibility workarounds that might as well be outright obfuscation (remember, you don't get the *comments* - just the actually compiled code). Are you willing to spend a few hundred thousand hours to satisfy your idle curiosity? :P

Comment: Thanks for the answer, like I said previously there wasn't any practical basis for my question. I wouldn't personally be up for decompiling it, I was really thinking about the possibilities of applying the obfuscation methods Windows uses to other software, but like you said, part of that is due to the magnitude of the OS.

Comment: @user7126040 An optimizing native compiler is a good enough obfuscation method in itself. Obfuscating managed code (.net/java) is a different story.

Comment: @user7126040 Obfuscation is pretty much useless, if you ask me. It may stop the most inept of decompilers, but the truth is, native compilers now produce heavily obfuscated assembly simply to be performant anyway. If you can read an optimized assembly output, there's not a lot more an obfuscator can do. They only have a tiny bit of effect on managed code, where by default the decompilation can get very close to the original source code even in rather complex cases, but again - that only deters people who don't reverse engineer at all.

Answer (score -1):

Decompiling Windows source code is not easy. It's very hard. The ONLY use I can come up with is to fix security vulnerabilities that Microsoft, being a company of pure inferiority and user-neglect, decide not to fix.